# L5 Using same form for store and update

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

As a L5 newbie i have a form and i am using it in order to edit data. I have links like previous,next,first and last in order to get records and edit them. I am using form model binding to see values on form. My purpose is using the same form for adding new records but since i use form model binding all input elements show up with their values. What should i do to add a new record by using the same form ? Any help would be appreciated

```
{!! Form::model($vehicle,['url' => '/pages/store']) !!}                                   
    <table style="width:650px; margin-left: 4px;" >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Model</td>
                <td>Brand</td>
                <td>License Plate</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{!! Form::text('id' ,null , ['readonly'], ['class' =>'textboxlong form-control', 'style'=>'height:23px;']) !!}</td>
                <td>{!! Form::text('model' ,null ,['class' =>'textboxlong form-control', 'style'=>'height:23px;']) !!}</td>
                <td>
                    {!! Form::select('brand', $brands, null, ['id'=>'brandBox', 'style' => 'width:150px;']) !!}
                </td>
                <td>{!! Form::text('licenseplate' ,null ,['class' =>'textboxlong form-control', 'style'=>'height:23px;']) !!}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="buttoncontainer">
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ URL::to( 'pages/vehicleprocess/' . $first -> id ) }}"><<</a>&nbsp;
        @if($previous)
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ URL::to( 'pages/vehicleprocess/' . $previous ) }}">PREVIOUS</a>&nbsp;
        @endif
        @if($next)
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ URL::to( 'pages/vehicleprocess/' . $next ) }}">NEXT</a>&nbsp;
        @endif
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ URL::to( 'pages/vehicleprocess/' . $last -> id ) }}">>></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a class="btn btn-default" id="add">EKLE</a>&nbsp;
        {!! Form::submit('EDIT', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}&nbsp;
        {!! Form::submit('NEW RECORD', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}&nbsp;
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: You want to add new record without refresh or what ?

Comment: I want to add a new record by using the same form.

Comment: Why not jquery with ajax call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would want to do is take everything inside the form and insert it into another `.blade.php` file.  I usually call them something like `form_partial.blade.php`.

Then you would have 2 additional blade files, one for store and one for edit.  In store, you would use `Form::open()` and then `@include('form_partial')` and then `Form::close()`

In your edit file, do the same except you would use `Form::model($model)` then `@include('form_partial')` and then `Form::close()`

Comment: i need to use `Form::model($model)` for editing and need an empty model for storing. It would be hard to manage it with your way

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same form for create by just passing in an empty model.

```
$vehicle = new Vehicle();

Form::model($vehicle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `@if` condition as well, for example, something like this:

```
@if(isset($vehicle))
    {!! Form::model($vehicle, ['url' => '/pages/'.$vehicle->id, 'method' => 'PATCH']) !!}
@else
    {!! Form::open(['url' => '/pages/store']) !!}
@endif
```

So, when you load the form for editing, you pass the `$vehicle` variable so the `Form::model` would be used, otherwise `Form::open` would be used with `$vehicle` variable when loading the form for creating a new `Vehicle`.

Comment: I guess the vehicle will always be set and the second form never appears

Comment: No, that is not going to be always set if you don't pass the `$vehicle` variable when creating and that's an easy way.

Comment: What i mean is i am passing `$vehicle` to the view everytime which makes your suggestion useless

Comment: Yes, if you pass the `$vehicle` every time then this answer is useless but why would you pass `$vehicle` everytime other than `edit`?